# How to share VPN network access

Tags: openvpn, nat, bridge

I have got [this setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beUsS.jpg) with two LANs and OpenVPN infra.
I need to share the OpenVPN connection attached to Proxmox server (10.8.0.12) to the Proxmox VMs (192.168.0,1,2,3,...).

I was trying to use linux bridge on Proxmox:

```
iface vmbr2 inet static
        address 10.8.1.12/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.8.1.0/24' -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.8.1.0/24' -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

together with manual static routes on VMs - but it didn't worked.
On the other hand, quite similar setup (using iptables NAT on vmbr1) for sharing the internet to the Proxmox VMs is working correctly.

Could You pls point me in the right direction? Has anybody tried to setup such a sharing?

### Datails:

#### Proxmox server:

```
ip --brief a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
eno1             UP
eno2             DOWN
tun0             UNKNOWN        10.8.0.12/24 
vmbr0            UP             pu.bl.ic.ip/31 
vmbr1            UP             192.168.1.1/24   # the bridge for sharing internet ( it works )
vmbr2            UP             10.8.1.12/24     # I have made it in order to make a NAT --> OpenVPN network ( tun0 iface )
tap104i0         UNKNOWN
tap104i1         UNKNOWN
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ip r
default via pu.bl.ic.ip dev vmbr0 proto kernel onlink
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0       # OpenVPN route
10.8.1.0/24 dev vmbr2 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.1.12
192.168.1.0/24 dev vmbr1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

iptables-save


*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [555262:374327004]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [453390:357667405]
COMMIT


*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [3284:179456]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1275:103329]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [911:61638]
:PVEFW-Drop - [0:0]
:PVEFW-DropBroadcast - [0:0]
:PVEFW-FORWARD - [0:0]
:PVEFW-FWBR-IN - [0:0]
:PVEFW-FWBR-OUT - [0:0]
:PVEFW-HOST-IN - [0:0]
:PVEFW-HOST-OUT - [0:0]
:PVEFW-INPUT - [0:0]
:PVEFW-OUTPUT - [0:0]
:PVEFW-Reject - [0:0]
:PVEFW-SET-ACCEPT-MARK - [0:0]
:PVEFW-logflags - [0:0]
:PVEFW-reject - [0:0]
:PVEFW-smurflog - [0:0]
:PVEFW-smurfs - [0:0]
:PVEFW-tcpflags - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j PVEFW-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j PVEFW-FORWARD
-A OUTPUT -j PVEFW-OUTPUT
-A PVEFW-Drop -p tcp -m tcp --dport 43 -j PVEFW-reject
-A PVEFW-Drop -j PVEFW-DropBroadcast
-A PVEFW-Drop -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3/4 -j ACCEPT
-A PVEFW-Drop -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A PVEFW-Drop -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Drop -p udp -m multiport --dports 135,445 -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Drop -p udp -m udp --dport 137:139 -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Drop -p udp -m udp --sport 137 --dport 1024:65535 -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Drop -p tcp -m multiport --dports 135,139,445 -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Drop -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Drop -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Drop -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Drop -m comment --comment "PVESIG:WDy2wbFe7jNYEyoO3QhUELZ4mIQ"
-A PVEFW-DropBroadcast -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j DROP
-A PVEFW-DropBroadcast -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j DROP
-A PVEFW-DropBroadcast -m addrtype --dst-type ANYCAST -j DROP
-A PVEFW-DropBroadcast -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j DROP
-A PVEFW-DropBroadcast -m comment --comment "PVESIG:NyjHNAtFbkH7WGLamPpdVnxHy4w"
-A PVEFW-FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A PVEFW-FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A PVEFW-FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in fwln+ --physdev-is-bridged -j PVEFW-FWBR-IN
-A PVEFW-FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-out fwln+ --physdev-is-bridged -j PVEFW-FWBR-OUT
-A PVEFW-FORWARD -m comment --comment "PVESIG:qnNexOcGa+y+jebd4dAUqFSp5nw"
-A PVEFW-FWBR-IN -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID,NEW -j PVEFW-smurfs
-A PVEFW-FWBR-IN -m comment --comment "PVESIG:Ijl7/xz0DD7LF91MlLCz0ybZBE0"
-A PVEFW-FWBR-OUT -m comment --comment "PVESIG:2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk"
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID,NEW -j PVEFW-smurfs
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -p igmp -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8006 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1976 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -p tcp -m set --match-set PVEFW-0-management-v4 src -m tcp --dport 8006 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -p tcp -m set --match-set PVEFW-0-management-v4 src -m tcp --dport 5900:5999 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -p tcp -m set --match-set PVEFW-0-management-v4 src -m tcp --dport 3128 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -p tcp -m set --match-set PVEFW-0-management-v4 src -m tcp --dport 22 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -p tcp -m set --match-set PVEFW-0-management-v4 src -m tcp --dport 60000:60050 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -j PVEFW-Drop
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -j DROP
-A PVEFW-HOST-IN -m comment --comment "PVESIG:ViyFkNMCk/yw1BHHyqmUbyOtAzs"
-A PVEFW-HOST-OUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A PVEFW-HOST-OUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A PVEFW-HOST-OUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A PVEFW-HOST-OUT -p igmp -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-OUT -d pu.bl.ic.ip/31 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8006 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-OUT -d pu.bl.ic.ip/31 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-OUT -d pu.bl.ic.ip/31 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5900:5999 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-OUT -d pu.bl.ic.ip/31 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3128 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-OUT -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-HOST-OUT -m comment --comment "PVESIG:vW12F8KvRxI4X2sYVlSVEYYgIjM"
-A PVEFW-INPUT -j PVEFW-HOST-IN
-A PVEFW-INPUT -m comment --comment "PVESIG:+5iMmLaxKXynOB/+5xibfx7WhFk"
-A PVEFW-OUTPUT -j PVEFW-HOST-OUT
-A PVEFW-OUTPUT -m comment --comment "PVESIG:LjHoZeSSiWAG3+2ZAyL/xuEehd0"
-A PVEFW-Reject -p tcp -m tcp --dport 43 -j PVEFW-reject
-A PVEFW-Reject -j PVEFW-DropBroadcast
-A PVEFW-Reject -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3/4 -j ACCEPT
-A PVEFW-Reject -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A PVEFW-Reject -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Reject -p udp -m multiport --dports 135,445 -j PVEFW-reject
-A PVEFW-Reject -p udp -m udp --dport 137:139 -j PVEFW-reject
-A PVEFW-Reject -p udp -m udp --sport 137 --dport 1024:65535 -j PVEFW-reject
-A PVEFW-Reject -p tcp -m multiport --dports 135,139,445 -j PVEFW-reject
-A PVEFW-Reject -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Reject -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Reject -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j DROP
-A PVEFW-Reject -m comment --comment "PVESIG:CZJnIN6rAdpu+ej59QPr9+laMUo"
-A PVEFW-SET-ACCEPT-MARK -j MARK --set-xmark 0x80000000/0x80000000
-A PVEFW-SET-ACCEPT-MARK -m comment --comment "PVESIG:Hg/OIgIwJChBUcWU8Xnjhdd2jUY"
-A PVEFW-logflags -j DROP
-A PVEFW-logflags -m comment --comment "PVESIG:MN4PH1oPZeABMuWr64RrygPfW7A"
-A PVEFW-reject -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j DROP
-A PVEFW-reject -s 224.0.0.0/4 -j DROP
-A PVEFW-reject -p icmp -j DROP
-A PVEFW-reject -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A PVEFW-reject -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A PVEFW-reject -p icmp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
-A PVEFW-reject -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A PVEFW-reject -m comment --comment "PVESIG:Jlkrtle1mDdtxDeI9QaDSL++Npc"
-A PVEFW-smurflog -j DROP
-A PVEFW-smurflog -m comment --comment "PVESIG:2gfT1VMkfr0JL6OccRXTGXo+1qk"
-A PVEFW-smurfs -s 0.0.0.0/32 -j RETURN
-A PVEFW-smurfs -m addrtype --src-type BROADCAST -g PVEFW-smurflog
-A PVEFW-smurfs -s 224.0.0.0/4 -g PVEFW-smurflog
-A PVEFW-smurfs -m comment --comment "PVESIG:HssVe5QCBXd5mc9kC88749+7fag"
-A PVEFW-tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -g PVEFW-logflags
-A PVEFW-tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -g PVEFW-logflags
-A PVEFW-tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -g PVEFW-logflags
-A PVEFW-tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -g PVEFW-logflags
-A PVEFW-tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --sport 0 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -g PVEFW-logflags
-A PVEFW-tcpflags -m comment --comment "PVESIG:CMFojwNPqllyqD67NeI5m+bP5mo"
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Oct 26 12:21:12 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Oct 26 12:21:12 


*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1409:85920]
:INPUT ACCEPT [984:53816]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [459:29557]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [461:29725]
-A PREROUTING -d 10.8.0.12/32 -i vmbr2 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.3
-A PREROUTING -d 10.8.0.3/32 -i vmbr2 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.1.104
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
Completed on Tue Oct 26 12:21:12 2021
```

#### Proxmox VM:

```
ip --brief a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 
ens18            UP             192.168.1.104/24
ens19            UP             10.8.1.104/24 



ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev ens18 proto static
10.8.1.0/24 dev ens19 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.1.104
192.168.1.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.104
```

Comment: All routes are in place? Please, show `ip addr` (you may hide vm interfaces that participate in the bridge and not having addresses), `ip route`, `iptables-save` of running system when it is supposed to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, I have supplemented my original question with the details that you've asked me. Could you pls take a look if that clarifies you my setup?